# Can I use xilinx PLL's locked signal as a reset?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, reset

I'd like to make reset signal.
now I'm using the xilinx pll and I found that LOCKED_OUT signal.
can I use that LOCKED_OUT signal as reset my fpga?
the follow is some example for my idea of question.

```
 pll100 u_pll100(
        .CLKIN1_IN  (aclk       ),
        .RST_IN     (!rst   ),
                .CLKOUT0_OUT(clk_19 ), 
                .CLKOUT1_OUT(clk_24 ), 
                .LOCKED_OUT (lock   )
                );

assign areset_n = lock;

always @(posedge wr_clk or negedge areset_n)                                           
begin   
        if(!areset_n) begin 
                data_d0 <=0;                                                      
                end                                                                   
        else begin
                data_d0 <= data;                                              
                end                                                                   
end
```

Comment: And what is exactly the rst input signal to the PLL?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but be sure to treat it as an asynchronous reset, especially if you aren't using the PLL output directly as your clock. I'm fairly sure that the PLL does not synchronize the LOCKED_OUT signal internally.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use the locked signal as reset as the only reset in the code (except for the clock manager itself), whenever you use any clock manager IPcore in a FPGA. This ensures that all the clocks coming out of the clock manager are stable.